# Why does not Iterator have add method whereas List Iterator has one in Java?

Tags: java

Can any one guide why is it design like this.

Iterator does not have add() method but List Iterator has one in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often an `Iterable` object might be immutable. A more specialized `Iterator` that knows the underlying object does support adding elements, could implement that feature. Like the case with `ListIterator`.

To be fair @Eran's answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 14):

My original thought was, like some of the other answers, to say that `Iterator` might be implemented by an immutable class. However, that answer is not enough, since Iterator does have a `delete` method (even though it doesn't have to be supported in all implementations).

I think a better reason for not having `insert` in `Iterator` is that it would have a meaning only in ordered data structures (such as lists). For example, there is no meaning to adding an element to a `Set` via an iterator of that `Set`.

Comment: There _IS_ "meaning" in adding elements to a Set, the trouble is that there's no predicting "where" the insert is going to happen wrt the current "position" of the iterator in the set.  (+1 nonetheless for being first)

Comment: @ErwinSmout I meant that adding an element to the Set via an iterator wouldn't have any added value compared to simply adding directly to the Set, since the elements of the Set are not ordered, so the current position of the iterator would have no effect on where the new element is added.

Answer (score 3):

- Iterator will be used to iterate through a set/list/queue. All these
  collections have their own logic for ordering. For e.g "TreeSet" is a
  sorted data structure. Now while iterating through a treeSet of let
  {2,5,7,19,22}; when the cursor is at 7 ,programmer tries to add 29.
  in this scenario treeset would be dis-sorted and corrupted.Hence add
  method should not be allowed.
- But in remove () we are only deleting an element from a particular
  position which can never harm the ordering. So its allowed.
- Coming to ListIterator which allows add(). Remember its used only for
  List, which maintains order of its elements according to insertion
  order.So if we add an element at any given point , the ordering
  algorithm wont be hampered.

Answer (score 1):

Lists differ from Iterable collections in general in that a well-defined ordinal position of all the items in the list, and a well-defined ordinal position within the list of any iterator over it, is availbable/known.

As a consequence, a sensible definition for an insert operation through an Iterator is possible if and only if what is being iterated over is such a list.

The same does not hold for, say, HashSets and TreeSets.  With such collections, there's no predicting in general whether the insert will be "before" or "after" the current position of the iterator.  Thus there's no predicting in general whether the iterator will still run into elements that were inserted during the iteration or not.  Thus such a feature would give rise, in a sense, to erratic/random/unpredictable behaviour.  I wouldn't include an insert() feature either if I had to design the language.

Comment: The issue is not predicting if iterator will go over these inserted values or not. In fact I doubt there are any technical difficulties to implement either behavior. Best answer is IMO @Eran's.

Answer (score 1):

ListIterator lets u add an element after the element which it has recently read. As adding an element to a List is a less expensive operation ( because it allows duplicates ) addition is allowed. The iterator does not need to traverse the list back and forth while inserting into a list. This might be a reason why traversal using a ListIterator allows addition of an element. 
Also an extension to this logic would apply to the delete option as because for deletion we need to traverse through the whole collection before an element can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/search?q=java+iterator+insert+rationale :

Java Collections API Design FAQ - Oracle Documentation
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html :

> ```
> Oracle Technology Network
> Software Downloads
> Documentation
> ```
>
> Java Collections API Design FAQ
>
> Collection Interface
>
> 6. Why don't you provide an Iterator.add method?
>
>    The semantics are unclear, given that the contract for Iterator makes no guarantees about the order of iteration. Note, however, that
>      ListIterator does provide an add operation, as it does guarantee the
>      order of the iteration.

They mean that it is unclear what the semantics should be for unordered iteratables.

There are reasonable semantics choices for arbitrary unordered iteratables if performance didn't matter, eg the added element either won't or will or might turn up under further iteration. But under each of these choices being able to iterate and insert in general involves a performance hit compared to iterate-only behaviour. Performance does matter, so there is no reasonable semantics choice.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ordering argument that is backed by Oracle's [Java Collections API Design FAQ](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#a10), I thought of the following argument as well.

`Iterator` has been designed for iterating all sorts of collections in Java. Like suggested by others, a `Set` collection does not allow duplicate entries or alternatively some collections (for example, `BlockingQueue`) do not allow `null` values.

Adding `add()` and `set()` operations to `Iterator` can potentially result in an operation that is not supported by an underlying collection (however unlike `remove()` it would depend on the value passed).

On the other hand, in `ListIterator` these methods have been designed to deal with this situation. They would both throw `IllegalArgumentException` if some aspect of the element prevents it from being added to the list.

Answer (score -1):

`Iterator` is for iterating, not adding objects.

`List` on the other hand is iterable (therefore it has `Iterator`) but also it is able to manage entities, therefore the `add`.

See definition of `Iterable` and `List` to see what is their purpose.

Comment: Iterators do have remove() methods.

Comment: Yes, this is good point I didn't realize at the time of writing.